# Where in my class should i populate MemoryCache?

Tags: c#, memorycache

I have a class that returns a cache, usage currently:

```
var cache = new ProductCache().Get();
```

then `cache` is a `List<>` that can be enumerated.

question is really should i populate this cache when `ProductCache()` is instantiated in the constructor, or when it is retrieved?

Option 1:

```
 public class ProductCache
    {
        private readonly string key = "Product";
        private readonly object cacheLock = new object();
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

        public ProductCache()
        {
        }

        public List<string> Get()
        {
            // Try to return.
            var data = cache.Get(key) as List<string>;

            if (data != null)
                return data;

            lock (cacheLock)
            {
                // Check again.
                data = cache.Get(key) as List<string>;

                if (data != null)
                    return data;

                // Populate, and return.
                data = PopulateFromElsewhere();
                cache.Set(key, data, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(20));
                return data;
            }
        }

        private List<string> PopulateFromElsewhere()
        {
            return new List<string> { "Ball", "Stick" };
        }
    }
```

Option 2:

```
public class ProductCache
{
    private readonly string key = "Product";
    private readonly object cacheLock = new object();
    ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

    public ProductCache()
    {
        var data = cache.Get(key);

        if (data != null)
            return;

        lock (cacheLock)
        {
            // Check again.
            data = cache.Get(key);

            if (data != null)
                return;

            // Populate, and return.
            PopulateFromElsewhere();
        }
    }

    public List<string> Get()
    {
        return cache.Get(key) as List<string>;
    }

    private void PopulateFromElsewhere()
    {
        var data = new List<string> { "Ball", "Stick" };
        cache.Set(key, data, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(20));
    }
}
```

is the second option thread safe (enough)? i *think* the first one is....

there are other caches too.. and they are all similar, so i was planning on putting all the actual locking / loading behaviour in an abstract class

```
var storeCache = new StoreCache().Get();
var otherCache = new OtherCache().Get();
```

I guess the other option is a static class, but then there would need to be duplication of the locking mechanisms as i can't make that abstract... that could be quite nice, and used like...

```
var cache = GlobalCache.Stores();
```

Comment: You don't need to use lock in constructor in your Option 2 cause it reall useless. But your Option 2 is worse cause constructor should not contain any logic. But I don't understand your `PopulateFromElsewhere` in Option 1...

Comment: PopulateFromElsewhere is just a call to a file, or a Db, to get the data that actually goes in to the cache... in this example it's just a list of strings  if i go with option 1 my 'cache loading' logic is bundled up inside the get, what if i want to overload the get witha param or something.. that's why i was considienrg loading the cache when a new class was initialised.

Comment: But in your example Option 1 it doesn't populate your cache just returns back a list.

Comment: @xneg yes it does, to a var called `data` than then enters the cache as `cache.Set(key, data, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(20));`

Comment: In your Option 2 not in Option 1. Anyway I think Option 1 is preferable.

Comment: ok, but as per the additional comment i added about the cache loading logic being bundled within the `get` method, seems clunky... also, any comments on the usage ?

Comment: On the contrary, you Option 1 is the right way for using cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184473/discussion-between-m1nkeh-and-xneg).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your cache logic but want flexibility in your child classes you could use Template method pattern:

```
public abstract class BaseCache
{
  private readonly object cacheLock = new object();
  protected ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

  public List<string> Get()
  {
        // for example. It could be anywhere and return any type.
        ChildLogic();

        var data = cache.Get(key);

        if (data != null)
            return;

        lock (cacheLock)
        {
            // Check again.
            data = cache.Get(key);

            if (data != null)
                return;

            // Populate, and return.
            PopulateFromElsewhere();
        }
  }

  protected abstract void ChildLogic();
  protected abstract void PopulateFromElsewhere();
}
```

And then in your child classes you should implement `ChildLogic()` and `PopulateFromElsewhere()` any way you want.

Of course you are not required to have method `ChildLogic()` at all.